# Project Management theme or plugin for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, project-management, themes

I have several home renovation / improvement projects coming and I need to work with my wife to share ideas online since it is easier to keep track of photos and links to website for ideas. I am planning to use Wordpress for tracking. We tried Basecamp and it is very complicated for her. I am thinking about using some kind of theme of plugin of Wordpress so that we can upload photos, add task (as a post or similar). Then at the front index page, it would show all list of tasks and small photos. Very simple one page.

Any good project management or task management out there working with Wordpress? I searched online and most are out of date.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a [Client Area Wordpress theme](http://clients.chrisgarnerart.com/news/using-wordpress-as-a-task-management-tool/) because I needed something like this myself. Its compatible with BuddyPress as well which the latest version of CollabPress can use now.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to give [CollabPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/collabpress/) a shot, it was last updated on 9-23-11.